# Rails filter params before creating/updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to add user privileges to an existing app that was designed without user privilege in mind. ie) If you are logged in, then you can create, update, and delete objects.

The application is using Rails 4, so I can take advantage of strong parameters.

I need to add a new user level that can only edit a model's nested attributes. So I thought about filtering out the params variable before the parent model is updated, created.

How can I filter out the `params` variable before the model is updated or created?

Answer (score 0):

You will need some sort of Authorization methodology.  There are gems that can help with this, but I would recommend reading at least this chapter of the rails tutorial.

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec-authorization

You might want to read the whole thing, it is an excellent intro to rails.

Answer (score 0):

I use something similar to the following code

```
# model controller pseudocode
def create
  Model.create!(create_params)
end

def update
  @model.update_attributes(update_params)
end

private
def create_params
  params.require(:model).permit(:some_attr)
end

def update_params
  params.require(:model).permit(:totally_different_attr)
end
```